# Exception caused by AppDomain when it shouldn't?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I am working on my MCTS and currently studying the AppDomain functionality. But I am running into something unclear. `AppDomain` should be capturing `Exception` and allow the domain to safely unload. (With the possible exception of the `StackOverflowException` as suggested elsewhere)

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
setup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
Evidence adevidence = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence;
domain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(domain_UnhandledException);
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain", adevidence, setup);
```

When I decide to create an instance of the example class in an assembly I created for this purpose I should be getting a safe, restricted Domain which will capture errors that occur and can be safely unloaded. At least this is how I understand it from my study book.

```
var type = (IDoSomeWork) domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("Library1", "Library1.Class1");
type.Run();
```

This throws an exception however on `type.Run()` (since I made it that way). But shouldn't the `AppDomain` capture it safely? Isn't that why we have an `AppDomain`?

**UPDATE:**

As requested, I have included the definition of the `Library1.Class1`. Also, for clarity, the `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` has no influence on capturing the exception and isn't relevant to the question.

```
[Serializable]
public class Class1 : MarshalByRefObject, IDoSomeWork
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("{0}", this.ToString()));
    }
}
```

I have verified that it runs in `MyDomain`.

Comment: Give the definition of Library1.Class1 please.

Answer (score 2):

The `UnhandledException` event does not *capture* the exceptions in the traditional sense, like a try-catch block (to the best of my knowledge), it is merely an information point, allowing you to perform logging and such tasks.

Quoted from the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx):

> This event provides notification of
>   uncaught exceptions. It allows the
>   application to log information about
>   the exception before the system
>   default handler reports the exception
>   to the user and terminates the
>   application.

So the exception will still bubble up to the system default exception handler.

Comment: Why wouldn't the exception stay contained within the ApplicationDomain though? I'm not sure this completely answered the question.

Comment: @Taylor: because the event is not designed to work like that. The documentation clearly states that the event handler allows the application to collect information *before the system default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the application*. It is not the purpose of the event to work as a global catch block.

Comment: I think the main point of the question is about why the default AppDomain is getting the exception. For example, what would happen if there was was no UnhandledExceptionEventHandler for the custom (non-default) domain?

Comment: @Taylor: re-reading the question and I my answer I see your confusion, and must say that I start to share it. I'll let the answer be for now (short of time with other tasks), but will come back after some experimentation later, unless someone else already shed some light on the issue until then.

Comment: I asked a question regarding AppDomains recently and there seemed to be some disagreement related to this topic as well (comments on Reed Copsey's answer). See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639244/common-uses-and-best-practices-for-application-domains-in-net

Answer (score 0):

```
 AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf MyExceptionHandler.HandleException
```

Adds a top-level exception handler but it might not do what you want in this case.